# how to compile projects with cross referencing packages in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

pkg A refers a class in pkg B, and vice versa.  Is this allowed?

```
package A;
import B.B11;
class A1 {
...
}

package B; 
import A.A11;
class B1 {
...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**Yes, it is allowed** but discouraged. This is called cycle dependency between packages.

To compile it you compile whole source directory and compiler takes care of these dependencies.

Comment: do you mean I have to put the two packages in the same project?

Comment: Yes, exactly this is what you need to do.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure the question you are asking, but if you asking if classes in different packages within the same project can reference each other, the answer is yes.  One thing in your example that you might want to check, if you do not offer a modifier (public, for instance), then java assumes package level and classes in a different package will not be able to access them.

[Read this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) to learn more about access modifiers.

Like Grzegorz said, if you're attempting to create a cyclical dependency, it would be strongly discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

Completely allowed, but strongly discouraged.